# Failed to load class “org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder” error

Tags: maven, tomcat, intellij-idea, log4j, slf4j

I'm opening this post after I couldn't find a solution in the post:
[Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587627/failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder-error)

I also opened a Maven project in IntelliJ and got the following error after choosing the option 'redeploy' in tomcat7 plugin:

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:
>   See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
>   details.

In the attached link, it was recommended to go to File-> Project Structure -> Artifacts and check for errors. This is what I see:
[image]

I also have the following dependencies in pom.xml file:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>
```

Can you please help me finding the error?

Comment: please show what you see in "Project structure" when you click on "Libraries". Add it to your question.

Answer (score 14):

Maybe there are two issues:

1. version mismatching of your dependencies
2. an issue when you deploy your application

For reproducing your error I've created this mini program:

```java
package de.so;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class DemoSlf4j
{
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoSlf4j.class);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        logger.error("Start ...");
    }
}
```

with **only these** dependencies (same as you used) in pom.xml:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I've got these messages:

> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J: Found
>   binding in
>   [jar:file:/D:/Maven-Repo/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.5.6/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/D:/Maven-Repo/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.21/slf4j-simple-1.7.21.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class] SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an
>   explanation. SLF4J: Actual binding is of type
>   [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory] SLF4J: The requested version 1.5.6
>   by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6, 1.7] SLF4J: See
>   http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
>   log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (de.so.DemoSlf4j).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

When I use these dependencies, everything is fine. Look at the versions!

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version> <!-- or use LATEST -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version> <!-- or use LATEST -->
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If you are using `org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.21` instead of `slf4j-simple` (what is more likely for production purposes), you'll get:

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (de.so.DemoSlf4j).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. log4j:WARN See
>   http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

So do this:

- look in your project dependencies if there are other artifacts which have cascading dependencies to logging frameworks (log4j, slf4f, ...).
- check if your dependencies are proper deployed to your Tomcat. (.../WEB-INF/lib)
- check the versions

Comment: I was working in Intellij on Kafka version 2.4.1 and it only had a dependency of slf4j-api 1.7.28 listed in the gradle side panel. As you mentioned in this post, I added the slf4j-simple with the same version and it fixed it. I don't understand why but thank you!

Comment: this saved my life

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you get cracked jar  in your project ,check it in debug model detail,I had this problem too, when I build with debug model, I see warning of:

`/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.11/logback-classic-1.1.11.jar` ,so remove it ,and build it again.  problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You are providing a log api, and two different implementations, `slf4j-log4j12` and `slf4j-simple`. I had the same issue, but in my case, it gave me an error message asking me to 'remove one' from class path.

You can try removing either `slf4j-simple` or `slf4j-log4j12` from dependencies, clean and build project again.

Answer (score 0):

I met with the same issue. I fixed it by adding the following dependencies to my POM.xml file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

for the ${slf4j.version}, please assign the latest version number:

```
<properties>
    ...
    <slf4j.version>1.7.30</slf4j.version>
</properties>
```