# SLF4J Logger binding not working

Tags: java, spring, maven, logging, slf4j

I am trying to enable my SLF4J logger but get the following console message:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Even after I have added these two dependencies to my pom.xml but still have the same message:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

I am testing out my logger like this

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
...
//Logger
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Hello.class);
...
logger.info("Test - - - Log message...");
```

I am new to Spring/Maven and thought this would be easy to solve but have had no success...

Edit:
Here is my Maven pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myfakecompany.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringApp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Spring MVC Webapp</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven MILESTONE Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <build>
        <finalName>SpringMVCApp</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <path>/</path>
                        <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Edit 2:
@Ceki, here is the mvn dependency:tree output...

```
[INFO] com.myfakecompany.project:SpringApp:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-cassandra:jar:1.4.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-cql:jar:1.4.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:19.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.12.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-dse:jar:2.1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:jar:2.1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.0.27.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.0.27.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  \- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.0.27.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.0.27.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.0.27.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.codahale.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] \- org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.7.5:compile
```

Comment: According to the link, http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder, you should only be using one dependency, not two... You should just include slf4j-simple in your pom.xml

Comment: Can you please add the output of "mvn dependency:tree" to your question?

Comment: @ryekayo It's perfectly OK to declare slf4j-api. However, it will be pulled in by the slf4j-simple declaration. Thus, the slf4j-api is redundant if a binding such as slf4j-simple is declared.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587627/failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder-error)

Comment: @Ceki, I have added the output in Edit 2 and I believe the link you posted could be a possible solution, however the IDE has changed in the years since that has been posted and not sure how to navigate to the tabs talha06 is specifying...

Comment: If you are using IntelliJ IDEA, then the likelihood of this question being a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587627/failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder-error is quite high. If so, you should close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @Ceki sorry, I did not see the latest edit...

Comment: @Ceki I followed your latest edit suggestion in that post, but I do not have anything under the Project Structure->Artifacts list. Since it is still unsolved I will wait to make sure it is a duplicate...

Comment: Update: My logger is now working although I am unsure exactly what I did to make it work either of 2 things: 1) Under Project Structure->Artifacts tab, I clicked add new and added new artifact then deleted it OR 2) Restarted application and computer. Sorry I am unable to determine exactly what the solution was.

Answer (score 0):

Update: My logger is now working although I am unsure exactly what I did to make it work either of 2 things: 1) Under Project Structure->Artifacts tab, I clicked add new and added new artifact then deleted it OR 2) Restarted application and computer. Sorry I am unable to determine exactly what the solution was.